# how to propagate uncertainty in probability values

Tags: error-propagation

If you are modeling probability of events (eg classic dice rolls or coin tosses) but want to represent probabilities as normal distributions, how do you propagate the uncertainty from individual events into uncertainty of your final probability?

As an example, take rolls of two different 4-sided dice: if you are uncertain about the evenness of the first die, you may model the probability of rolling a 1 to be 0.25 +/- 0.05. A second die may have different unnevenness, so after rolling it many times, you model its probability of rolling a 1 to be 0.2 +/- 0.02.  The expected probability of rolling consecutive 1s is 0.05, but what is the standard error? The standard ways of propagating uncertainty (sum of variance for each involved independent variable) don't seem to apply very well:

If I normalize (dividing the std errors by the expected values before squaring them), low probability events end up contributing an unreasonably high amount of error. For instance, an event with probability 0.05 +/- 0.05 would contribute 1 to the sum of variances. If you were trying to determine the likelihood of that event happening 3 times, you would get 1.25E-4 +/- 2.17E-4 (normalized: 1.73).
Consider the other outcome at 0.95 +/- 0.05 likely. It contributes a 0.0028 term for the variance. The likelihood of that event happening 3 times would be 0.86 +/- 0.08 (normalized: 0.091). I’d expect the normalized standard errors to match; shouldn’t that be symmetrical?

If I don’t normalize, it’s weird in different ways: the standard error is consistent for either outcome, but it grows at an enormous rate: 4 consecutive events yield a standard error of 0.1, and a standard error of 0.5 for 100. Even if the true mean was at +1 standard error (0.1), that expected value would be 10E-100, not 0.5.

I get that approximating probabilities with normal distributions is a little problematic – the tails fall out of the 0-1 bounds. Are either of these ways right? Is there a better way to model uncertainty of a probability expected value without deep stats voodoo?

Comment: Could you give a realistic example of the data you have? With the dice example, there is no need for representing the data as uncertainties, you can use the raw data and the statistical model would learn the uncertainties from it.

Comment: I'm reticent to do so - I posted the same question a week ago with the full context and it confused the one person who responded, who essentially called me stupid without speaking to anything in my question. My question was subsequently closed as "needing more information".
This is as simple and uncomplicated as I can get the problem.

Comment: As stated like this, your question can be answered without even mentioning error propagation. So it you want to get useful answer, you would need to make it more precise.

Comment: The physical situation described here makes no sense, because a die doesn't change its characteristics from one roll to the next (at least not in any appreciable way); but it becomes meaningful if you suppose *different dice* are rolled each time and that the properties of those dice vary as described.  The form of "uncertainty" you refer to is vague, though.  Could you be more explicit about what your estimator is and how you are assessing uncertainty, and uncertainty of what parameter(s)?

Comment: My source data is event likelihoods given as ranges, given by experts because experimental data is unavailable. It is presented as scenarios: in a given year, how likely will a particular manufacturing machine have a failure that takes it out of commission for more than a week? The experts have decent predictive abilities based on historic failures of similiar equipment, but are uncomfortable giving a single probability. Also, for some scenarios they are more confident. I am creating a model that combines the scenarios (many cascade and are interdependent) to show a picture of resilience.

Comment: presenting the uncertainty in their estimates is an important insight, as some capabilities are substantially less understood by our teams than others. Showing that our expected downtime/cost for some areas could vary widely may prompt investment in those areas.

Comment: Please, then, edit your post so that it reflects the situation you face rather than describing some abstract setup that might not accurately reflect every important aspect of the problem.